# Esta pergunta deve receber a tag "brasil"?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, tag-específica

A pergunta ["Como funciona o licenciamento de software no Brasil"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76564/215) possui - como o próprio título indica - um foco no Brasil, e a resposta-wiki também discorre em grande parte acerca da situação jurídica dos programas de computador neste país. Achei adequado dar-lhe a tag [brasil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brasil), e assim o fiz.

Mas depois fiquei na dúvida: a pergunta é *focada* no Brasil, mas não é de todo exclusiva pelo fato de abordar também em linhas gerais o licenciamento (*Copyright* é um assunto em que tratados internacionais meio que "ditam" como as leis específicas de cada país vão ser, de modo que há muita homogeneidade). Como a tag diz:

> Esta tag deve ser usada sempre que o assunto é específico para o Brasil e não tem relevância para quem desenvolve software para outros países. Um exemplo típico é relacionado a questões sobre tecnologias com intuito fiscal

Fiquei em dúvida se ela seria aplicável aqui. O que acham?

Comment: Eu acho mais "seguro" usar a tag, mesmo que parte do conteúdo se aplique a outros países.

Comment: Se aplica muito pouco a outros países, eu nem tenho conhecimento da legislação internacional. Só não coloquei a tag porque não lembrei dela mesmo, porque tomei até o cuidado de colocar isso no título. +1

Comment: O uso da *tag* não é excludente, basta ter algo importante na pergunta que justifique o seu uso, é válido. Seria problema apenas se o fato de ser Brasil fosse absolutamente tangencial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "*Mas depois fiquei na dúvida: a pergunta é focada no Brasil, mas não
>   é de todo exclusiva pelo fato de abordar também em linhas gerais o
>   licenciamento [...]*"

Não se preocupe. Ao meu ver, as tags servem *essencialmente* como marcadores adicionais para facilitar que alguém interessado encontre conteúdo relevante por determinado assunto. Enfim, é uma taxonomia dinâmica e colaborativa.

Alguém poderia argumentar que nesse sentido uma tag [brasil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brasil) seria inútil pois dificilmente alguém se interessaria pelo seu "conteúdo". Mas no mínimo ela serve para filtrar assuntos que se aplicam mais a esse país. A existência de outras tags, principalmente a tag [licença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licen%c3%a7a), já ajudam que o conteúdo seja localizado (e útil) para outros indivíduos em outros contextos.

> P.S.: Também nesse sentido, eu sugeriria editar o conteúdo da tag
>   [brasil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brasil) e trocar "não tem relevância" por algo do tipo "tem
>   pouca/menor relevância" ou "não necessariamente é relevante".